# How to sort users by max number of posts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to sort all my users by the number of their posts. Like:

```
User1(100 posts)
User2(90 posts)
User3(80 posts)
```

How can I do this in laravel elequont relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `withCount` to get the posts count without loading the relationship and sort the result using `posts_count`. You can also apply additional conditions if required. As a bonus you get the posts count with each user.

```
$users = User::withCount('posts')
    ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$data = User::select(DB::raw('users.*, count(*) as total_posts'))
    ->join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('total_posts', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get()-
>sortBy(function($users)
{
return $users->posts->count();
});
```